# Apache CXF Policy: Security configuration could not be detected (external policies)

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf, ws-security

For a few days I try to resolve following issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Security configuration could not be detected. Potential cause: Make sure jaxws:client element with name attribute value matching endpoint port is defined as well as a ws-security.signature.properties element within it.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:158)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getSignedDocument(Unknown Source)
    at pl.mycompany.epuap.TPSigning_TPSigning_Client.main(TPSigning_TPSigning_Client.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: Security configuration could not be detected. Potential cause: Make sure jaxws:client element with name attribute value matching endpoint port is defined as well as a ws-security.signature.properties element within it.
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.policyNotAsserted(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:315)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.getSignatureBuilder(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:1851)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignature(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:570)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:149)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AsymmetricBindingHandler.handleBinding(AsymmetricBindingHandler.java:98)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:176)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    ... 2 more
```

This happens when I try to call webservice: https://pz.gov.pl/pz-services/tpSigning?wsdl with external (referenced) policy: https://pz.gov.pl/pz-services/tpSigning?wsdl=wssec-policies.wsdl.

Here is my code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type",config.getKeystoreType());
properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password",config.getKeystorePass());
properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias",config.getKeystoreAlias());
properties.put("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file", config.getKeystoreFile());

outProps.put("cryptoProperties",properties);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP + " " +  WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);
//outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE);
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, config.getKeystoreAlias());
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, PasswordCallbackHandler.class.getName());
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_REF_ID,"cryptoProperties");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_PARTS, "{}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body");

WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

try{
    String s  = signing.addDocumentToSigning(doc, succesUrl, failureUrl, additionalInfo);
    return s;
}
```

As I noticed, the policies aren't at all loaded by CXF engine. I tried to load policies by interceptors, but the effect is the same.

The probelm occurs also in 2.7.18 as in 3.x version.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Regards
Mariusz

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing the "action" based approach to WS-Security, and the WS-SecurityPolicy driven approach. The WSDL you reference contains a security policy, and the CXF PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor will automatically take care of configuring security based on this. You just need to specify a few security configuration options, e.g. keystores. See here for more information: https://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html